# Einsum multiply each row with every one

Tags: python, numpy

im trying to find a special Matrix multiplication fully vectorized(without loops). Basically im trying to multipy each row with every row. for example`a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]) and b=np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])` then the result should be`([3,7,11],[6,14,22],[9,21,33]])`

(first all rows of "a" are multiplied with the first row of b, which gives us (3,7,11) and then the next row of a with all rows of be..)

Comment: You want the dot product `a.dot(b.T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `np.einsum`:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
>>> b = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])

>>> np.einsum('kj,ij->ik', a, b)
array([[ 3,  7, 11],                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
       [ 6, 14, 22],                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
       [ 9, 21, 33]])
```

This is equivalent to `b@a.T`, or equivalently `(a@b.T).T` like the other answers have already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dot function in numpy.

```
a = [[1,0],[0,1]]
b = [[4,1],[2,2]]
AdotB = np.dot(a,b)
```

AdotB is equal to [[4, 1],[2, 2]]

but you should be careful because it will raise ValueError if the last dimension of a is not the same size as the second-to-last dimension of b.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer:**

```
a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
b=np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])

res = a.dot(b.T).T

print('a =\n', a, '\n')
print('b =\n', b, '\n')
print('result =', '\n', res)
```

**The output:**

```
a =
 [[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]] 

b =
 [[1 1]
 [2 2]
 [3 3]] 

result = 
 [[ 3  7 11]
 [ 6 14 22]
 [ 9 21 33]]
```